# Nof replacements counter not working as expected

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, power-automate, flow, power-platform

[image]

Update item Noofassignments field has below expression and its working as expected

So when first time if for item modified with status active then Noofassignments counter will be 1 and Noofreplacements counter is 0

Second time, when item modified as status active then Noofassignments counter is 2 and Noofreplacements counter is 1

As per my below expression Noofreplacements counter is 0 for the first time and second time Noofreplacements counter is getting incremented by 2 but Noofreplacements field to be 1.

[image]

Update item for Noofreplacements field has below counter expression and its not working as expected.

[image]

Comment: In 2nd expression, you have to replace `Noofassignments` with `Noofreplacements`. let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot,it works but i got small clarity that for my above trigger i used recurrence is thats fine or should we use when items created or modified the reason for this question is that just to know the best practises ,if above my trigger fine or not also based on my requirement i perform above update item only when items modified so for some reason i developed using recurrence trigger ,please clarify

Comment: It depends on your requirements. If you are ok with updating column values periodically like once in a day/hour, you can use recurrence trigger. But if you want to update column values immediately after item created or modified, you have to change the current trigger.

Comment: Okay.Thanks as i am using update action in above flow then it should not result in the infinite loops right thats why i asked also there was another flow where i update items in the same list so thats why i asked

Comment: For such cases, you have to use trigger conditions or conditional checks to avoid multiple flow run/column value updates.

Comment: Okay. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used same expressions for both the columns, hence you are facing this problem.

**Solution**:

In 2nd expression for `Noofreplacements` column, you have to replace `Noofassignments` with `Noofreplacements`.